# Windows multipoint SDK MultipointSdk.Instance.Initialize(this) method not found?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-7, multipoint

I have downloaded a sample windows touch driver from here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ansont/archive/2010/01/30/custom-touch-devices.aspx

I have installed the Windows MultiPoint Mouse Software Development Kit 1.5.1 and cannot, for the life of me, figure out how to get past this error

when I look at the references MultipointSdk.Instance does not have an initialize method.

I have almost no experience with WPF and am getting a but lost.

This is the error I am getting

> Error  1   'Microsoft.Multipoint.Sdk.MultipointSdk' does not contain a definition for >'Initialize' and no extension method 'Initialize' accepting a first argument of type >'Microsoft.Multipoint.Sdk.MultipointSdk' could be found (are you missing a using >directive or an assembly reference?)    D:\MultiPointDevice\MultiPointDevice\MultipointTouchWindow.cs   31  36  MultiPointDevice

To give you some background on what I am trying to do. I am trying to extend project Sikuli to add touch input to the testing framework.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be you are missing the Reference. Please follow this:

- Right click on your project in Visual Studio.
- Click Add Reference
- Usually it will be present in .NET tab, if not, try Browse, go to Program Files\Microsoft MultiPoint SDK\bin\Microsoft.MultiPoint.Sdk.dll
- Press Ok and try again.

Another thing you should check is the Initialize method does not exist in 1.5. You can try the MultipointSdk.Instance.Register(this) for it.

Hope this help.